# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, rest, netbeans-7

I'm creating my first RestFul application, I'm very inexperienced in Java/Netbeans development.
I have a MySQL database with few tables; I created a new Web Application project and the Entity Classes based on the database. Then I created a RestFul Web Service based on the Entity Classes.
Everything good until this point.
When I try to test the RestFul service I get this **`error`**:

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'PERSON' does
not exist. Error Code: 30000 Call: SELECT id, email, first_name,
last_name FROM person Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Person
sql="SELECT id, email, first_name, last_name FROM person") root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException 
Internal
Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'PERSON' does
not exist. Error Code: 30000 Call: SELECT id, email, first_name,
last_name FROM person Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Person
sql="SELECT id, email, first_name, last_name FROM person") root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'PERSON' does not exist.
root cause

org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'PERSON' does not
exist.
```

This is my **`glassfish-resources.xml file`**

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_shoppinglist_db_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="shoppinglist_db"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="xxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoppinglist_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="shoppinglist_db" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_shoppinglist_db_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

And the **`persistence.xml file`**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ShoppingListPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>shoppinglist_db</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I checked and I do have access to the database and the tables exist.

Please help me, I don;t know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: The last line "org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException". Derby is java-based database. The config shows you using mysql. It looks like there is something wrong with your config and it is defaulting to derby.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot, this was driving me crazy. I created a new Connection Pool and assigned it to the JDBC Resource. I also had to enter server, database, username, password and URL in the Additional Properties panel.